# MongoDB: I want result set in order of other collection's data. What should be my schema & query?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoid

I have the following collections in MongoDB with displayed relations.[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbcv5.png)

Now I want all items as result set of query with following rules:
**1.** All items of passed menu_id.
**2.** If passed user id and the item_id is exists in user_item_status, the item should be come in the top of result set (order of items will depends, whether the entry of respective item is exists in another table or not)

What should be my query **with and without $lookup**?
Should I change the schema of collections?

Comment: 1. MongoDB is not RDBMS, so don't try to use it like RDBMS. 2. Why do you don't want to implement it on the app side?

Comment: @Neodan Thanks for the comment. Got you concern, But could you please guide me, How I should solve my purpose?